# How to search a selectbox item with autocomplete input in jquery ui

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My example: https://jsfiddle.net/anhoamth/1/

I have a selectbox that have size of 8 or more. And when i start tipping in the input field above the selectbox it should show me the autocomplete result in the selectbox. Is this possible to do this with jquery ui autocomplete ?

my html code:

```
<input type="text" name="selectType" id="selectType"><br><br>
<select name="type" id="type" size="8" style="width:173px">
   <option value="01">Samsung</option>
   <option value="02">Nokia</option>
   <option value="03">Apple</option>
   <option value="04">LG</option>
   <option value="05">Huawei</option>
</select><br><br>
<input type="text" name="showValue"><br><br>
```

my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name=type]').on('change', function(){
    var getOptionValue = $(this).val();
    setValue(getOptionValue);
  });

  function setValue(param) {
    $('input[name=showValue]').val(param);
  };

  function autocomplete() {
    $( "input[name=showValue]" ).autocomplete({
      // do something ??
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: so.. based on your example the desired result  is whenever you start typing into the input the combobox follows it? if i type n, then select nokia? then I press backspace then what? And what if there are multiple match for n?

Comment: When i press the backspace it should show me the whole list of options. If there are more results with n than it should show me the multiple matches.

Answer (score 1):

Use this handy plugin called [Select2](https://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjnmpGz4LzUAhWEmbQKHdjrBlIQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fselect2.github.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNEaQmOUYyg9I9kv0-wlXgjhsqbrGA&sig2=_WYglJSjg4GGcudpI3IgPQ&cad=rja)

```
<select class="phone-select" size="8" style="width:173px">
   <option value="01">Samsung</option>
   <option value="02">Nokia</option>
   <option value="03">Apple</option>
   <option value="04">LG</option>
   <option value="05">Huawei</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".phone-select").select2();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I need to have the size min 8

Comment: @GregOstry Just add the size property to the select element

Answer (score 0):

Look into this bootstrap plugin : https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

Hope this will useful.